# How to stop supervisord when a specific program stopped normally

Tags: docker, supervisord

I am using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) inside docker to run two processes:

1. the main process and
2. an ssh tunnel needed by the main process

When the main process stops normally, the ssh tunnel process stays alive forever, preventing the docker from stopping. This is problematic as the container runs as a Kubernetes job, that needs to terminate when the main process finished.

The question is, is it possible to kill the ssh tunnel when the main process stops or even better: stopping supervisord when the main process stopped?

Answer (score 0):

use `event listner`:

```
[eventlistener:MyMainProcessName]
command=kill -3 $(cat "/var/run/supervisord.pid")
process_name=MyMainProcessName
events=PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED, PROCESS_STATE_EXITED, PROCESS_STATE_FATAL
```

that will send `SIGQUIT` to Supervisor if that process stopped

Comment: Sure this is how it's meant to work? It seems like the command is immediately executed on supervisord's startup, no matter if the signal was received or not.

Comment: Yes sure I tested it also